# Let $F$ be a field; what does $(F)$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, notation

Let $L,K,L_1,L_2$ be fields where $L/K$ is a field extension and $K \leq L_1,L_2 \leq L$ be intermediate fields.
We define $L_1L_2$ to be the subfield of $L$ generated by $L_1 \cup L_2$

Show the following:
$L_1L_2=L_1(L_2)=L_2(L_1)$

My thoughts:
I am a little bit confused what the expression $L_1(L_2)$ means. I have not seen $()$ being defined for fields, nor what the multiplication of fields is.
The thing that comes to mind is:
Let R be a ring. For $S \subset R$

$(S):=\bigcap \{A: A$ is an Ideal of $R$ with $S \subseteq A\}$

In this case does $L_1L_2$ mean the multiplication of ideals which would be $L_1L_2:=\{a_1b_1+...+a_nb_n:a \in L_1, b \in L_2\}$

Is the meaning of the notation the same for fields as for rings?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a field $L$ and a subfield $F \subseteq L$ and a subset $A \subseteq L$, then $F (A)$ means the smallest subfield of $L$ containing both $F$ and $A$.
If you have subfields $F_1$ and $F_2$ then $F_1 F_2$ is the **compositum**, which is the smallest subfield of $L$ containing both $F_1$ and $F_2$.

Comment: Is there a more explicit way to write this down? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: This is explicit. "The smallest subfield such that ..." means you take all the subfields that satisfy the condition and then look at the one that is a subfield of all the rest. Often – and certainly in this case – it is the same as taking the intersection of all the subfields that satisfy the condition.

Comment: Thank you very much